# Calendar View Components for iPad (Commercial or Free)

Tags: ios, ipad

I am looking for iPad calendar components, something like the monthly calendar shown in iPhone, or the monthly table view in the Calendar app in the iPad. I have found interesting components made for iPhone, like Kal, but nothing similar that works universally. I prefer free components but also consider commercial solutions.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can find a couple of different calendar implementations [here](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar)